# Requiring superagent results in error in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, superagent, jestjs, refluxjs

I'm getting the following error when running Jest tests:

```
/Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/assets/app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js: /Users/hugo/src/feedback/www/assets/app/node_modules/superagent/node_modules/debug/node.js: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
```

If Jest automatically mocks out dependencies, shouldn't any file that requires `superagent` just get the mock of `superagent`? All the functions I have that even make an http request using it have been mocked out to just return test data without making the request. I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

**UPDATE**

I tried the manual mock found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/b6282f713605b619834f). It still gives me the same error.

Comment: I solved a similar issue with the superagent mock you linked to and using node 0.10.36.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using it though. I just switched back to regular old AJAX